# live update to dygraphs and impact on rangeSelector position

Tags: dygraphs

Looking at a dygraphs example for [updating a chart with live data](http://dygraphs.com/tests/dynamic-update.html), and then combining that with the dygraphs [rangeSelector](http://dygraphs.com/tests/range-selector.html), the resulting chart appears to work, except when you start dragging the handles of the rangeSelector.

The rangeSelector narrows the view of the main chart's data, but the main chart is frozen with the parameters, and the rangeSelector handles start **moving off the screen**, and only the rangeSelector graph shows updating data.

So I select a range with the range handle bars, and then as time passes, the range handles do not stay in place but instead get pushed off the slider, which makes them completely useless.
[image: sliding in wrong direction]

[image: now only one handle is left]

Moreover, when the range is selected, the data points in the main chart window become static, which is also useless. The range handlebars should not be moved unless the user moves them, and the real time data should be visibly moving through the main chart and the chart inside the range slider.

What I think the desired behavior would be:

1. The main chart should reflect the live updates. (It does not currently reflect updates when it is "stuck" on the window set by the movement of the range handles except when the handles begin to fall off the canvas.)
2. The main chart should remain restricted to the window imposed by the rangeSelector handles, where "window" means **not a beginning time and an end time**, but rather the **window of time** the handle spacing signifies. So even though the x-axis involves dates, it's as if this is a case where the range selector represents numbers (say 1 to 100), and if you slide the handles to show the range between 45-50, the 45-50 range should stay fixed: data updates should pass through the selection on both the small and main charts, and the range handles should not be pushed off the canvas.

Highcharts has an example of how this should work. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update
If you zoom to 1M, then drag the range to the far left, the range selector stays in place and the main chart still works.

Does dygraphs have a way to handle this, and is there a working example of this?

#### JSBin Example

http://jsbin.com/xevonixode/1/edit?html,js,output

#### HTML

```
<div id="div_g" style="width:800px; height:400px;"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var data = [];
      var t = new Date();
      for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        var x = new Date(t.getTime() - i * 1000);
        data.push([x, Math.random()]);
      }

      var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div_g"), data,
                          {
                            drawPoints: true,
                            showRoller: true,
                            valueRange: [0.0, 1.2],
                            color: '#4292c6',
                            labels: ['Time', 'Random'],
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            showRangeSelector: true    
                  });

      setInterval(function() {
        var x = new Date();  // current time
        var y = Math.random();
        data.push([x, y]);
        data.shift();
        g.updateOptions( { 'file': data } );
      }, 2000);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. If you want to reset the view window on every update, you can use the `dateWindow` parameter.

Comment: @danvk - tried again to clarify the question. Interesting that the same issue can be replicated in rickshaw if you move the right slide handle close to the left one. http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html

Comment: So you want the range handles to correspond to 45-50% of the data domain, whatever those values happen to be? Like I said before, if you want something unusual, you'll have to update the visible range yourself when you call `updateOptions`.

Comment: @danvk - Highcharts does it right, I just don't see how dygraphs can do it. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I actually find a way, it looks a bit like a trick but it works and it's using the interface functions of the dygraph object, so this solution looks legit enough.

```js
const goExtreme = dygraph.xAxisRange()[1] === dygraph.xAxisExtremes()[1];

dygraph.updateOptions({file: newData});

if (goExtreme) {
  dygraph.updateOptions({
    dateWindow: [dygraph.xAxisRange()[0], dygraph.xAxisExtremes()[1]]
  });
}
```

The trick here is to first update `updateOptions` to update the data in the graph as suggested in the example.
And then using the same function `updateOptions` to update the dateWindow with the current xAxis minumum and the xAxis maximum.
But we make sure the maximum is the extreme (`goExtreme`) before updating the data, because we don't want to cling the maximum when a range is selected inside the graph.